# Does Office 2007 offer capability to create protected pdf documents on its own?

Tags: security, pdf, microsoft-office

I am currently using Microsoft Office 2007 version. It has all the updates released so far. There is an option to save documents as pdf but I cannot find an option to protect them from copying its content or editing. In other words to make them read-only. I attempted to use Foxit Reader but it does not seem to have this option neither. There is a way to protect documents with MS Word own protection but that's not exactly what I am looking for. Does it exist a way for this which doesn't involve the necesity to purchase an additional software for that matter?

Can somebody help me here?

Answer (score 2):

> I am currently using Microsoft Office 2007 version. It has all the updates released so far. There is an option to save documents as PDF but I cannot find an option to protect them from copying its content or editing.

If you cannot find the option then Office 2007 does support the ability to create protected PDF documents.  While the PDF standard is open, certain features, are only supported by certain editors.

> I attempted to use Foxit Reader but it does not seem to have this option neither.

Creating protected PDF documents is one of the features, that only certain editors support, which means programs like Foxit will not respect the fact the document is protected.

> Does it exist a way for this which doesn't involve the necessity to purchase an additional software for that matter?

Since Office 2007 does not have the option you would need to purchase PDF authoring software that does support it.  **However, I will again point out that, programs like Foxit will not respect the fact the document is protected.**

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell - It might not be the answer you were looking for, but that does not change the fact the answer is indeed true, and is indeed an answer to the questions you asked in the question body.  Please keep the comment section to this answer limited to feedback about the actual answer.  *Requests for software recommendations will be ignored.*

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell - The only PDF editor I use is Acrobat Professional.  I also only use Office, not LibreOffice, so I couldn't speak to it's capabilities.  **However, this question is not about LibreOffice, it's specifically about the capabilities of Office 2007.**

Answer (score 0):

The PDF creation facility in Microsoft Office is a basic tool that does not offer
this type of protection. You would need a third party product to do password-protect.

A free PDF printer tool that supports protection is enough.

Examples are the
Adobe PDF printer installed with Adobe Acrobat or
[PrimoPDF](https://www.primopdf.com/).

Comment: I haven't used any open source printer.

Comment: Okay: Understood. It seems that as you indicated I'll have to use another software for that.

Comment: You could try the ones I listed. They are free.

Answer (score 0):

I have Office 2007 here on a VM and it does not support the protection feature. It just creates PDF documents. We use Adobe Acrobat for the feature you wish to use. That works fine.

Comment: Exactly this is what I was pointing at. And from the answers it seems that an additional software will supply the capabilities that i'm looking for.